# Store multiple data types in c++ data structure

Tags: c++, stack

I am making an interpreter for a programming language and i am working on the stack, but i have not been able to find an easy solution for a dynamic structure, that can contain multiple data types.  I need to be able to store multiple data-types in the structure, such as ints, longs, strings, etc.

Comment: You might want to read about unions.

Comment: Or possibly [Boost variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/variant.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use union:

```
union someUnion
{
  int a;
  long int b;
  char *string;
  //...any other needed type 
}
```

Take a look at [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/) for details. Union is often used in implementation of interpreters and compilers, e.g. in yacc (bison) and lex. BTW, you may check them, these can simplify much the coding of interpreter.

Comment: How would i do this with multiple types

Comment: Simply, variable `union someUnion someVar;` accepts `int`, `long int`, `char *`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

One relatively easy way to build such data structure would be using a `union`, like this:

```
union AnyType {
    int int_val;
    long long long_val;
    float float_val;
    double int_val;
    char char_val;
    char *char_prt;
};
```

This may not be the most economical, though, because the size of this structure is equal to that of the largest data type. A better approach would be using a "raw" memory chunk for your stack, dealing out its portions to the elements on the stack dynamically. You would need to pay attention to the alignment of the data, though, to avoid placing multibyte data at offsets that make access much slower or lead to runtime errors.